# R - How to make stacked bargraph for data over years with missing years

Tags: r, graphing

Here is my plot in R:
[image]

Here is the code that made the plot:

```
years <- c(1980, 1984, 1984, 1986, 1988)
pubs  <- c("book","book","poem","poem","book")
mypubs <- data.frame(years,pubs)
counts <- table(mypubs$pubs,mypubs$years)
barplot(counts,main="pubs per year",xlab="year",col=c("darkblue","red"),legend=rownames(counts))
```

This is time-series data, and there is no data for 1981, 1982, 1983, 1985 and 1987. The data is whether I read a book or a poem at any given time.

Is there a straightforward way to take `mypubs` and add holes for the missing years? I've tried doing a histogram plot, but I can't figure out how to make it reliably one bar for each year, and I can't figure out how to make a histogram do stacked colors.

Comment: I don't see any years with no data, you probably need to factorize the years in the original df.

Comment: There is no data for the year 1991. The original DF had "Year" as a column, and had a "yes/no" column. I've edited the example to make this more clear.

Comment: please dput your data, instead of describing it.

Comment: I have created a dramatically simpler example.

Comment: how do you expect to plot data not inside your `data.frame` ?

Comment: I don't expect to plot data not inside the data frame. I want a plot where there are spaces for three blank bars between the "1980" bar and the "1984" bar.

Comment: there is no `1981`,`1982` or `1983` in your `df`

Comment: Correct. And I'm not interested in adding them to the DF. But I'm interested in having the plot reflect that there are years being plotted. If I make a histogram I get the spacing correct, but I don't get stacked colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending Greg's answer from above, try this:

```
years <- c(1980, 1984, 1984, 1986, 1988)
pubs  <- c("book","book","poem","poem","book")
mypubs <- data.frame(years,pubs)

mypubs$years<-factor(mypubs$years, levels = as.character(1980:1990))

counts <- table(mypubs$pubs,mypubs$years)
barplot(counts,main="pubs per year",xlab="year",col=c("darkblue","red"),legend=rownames(counts))
```

The "factor" command with convert the years column into factors, while the optional "levels" will set the available levels

Comment: Hey, that's perfect! Just what I wanted. Thanks.  I did a `View(counts)` to see what the factor command did. It's very non-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Before you run your code, do something like:

```
mydata$B <- factor(mydata$B, levels=1990:2015)
```

Then run your code and you will see 0 counts for the years between 1990 and 2015 without data.  Modify the code if you want a different range of years.

Comment: That doesn't work. I get: `Error in levels:1990 : NA/NaN argument`.

Comment: @vy32, can you show the results of `str(mydata)` and the exact code that you ran?

Comment: Done. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @vy32, can you show the exact code and error?  I don't get any error when I run similar code and don't see where the error would be coming from.

Comment: I will create a simplified example and post.